# The Return URL from AJAX.BeginForm in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I Open Login form as pop up and I put Ajax.beginform in that in the login process as below.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", HttpMethod = "POST" },
    new { id = "Logonform", returnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
{
    ....
}
```

Now when I logged in then I have to redirected to current page whatever is like "Home or about us" .. Like If I open popup from about us page then its redirec to about us page.

My controller as below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel LM, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(LM.UserName, false);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            return Json(new { returnUrl = returnUrl });
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("UnSucessful", "User Name or Password is incorrect.");
    }
    return View(LM);
}
```

But every time I did not getting the retur URL and its going to "Home" page.

So Please let me know how to handle it.

Comment: You using ajax. Ajax will never redirect to another page.

Comment: Then How it will manage as per my scenario.

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. If you want to redirect, then just use a normal `@Html.BeginForm()`

Comment: You code (controller) is missing a `{` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the `returnUrl` from your action and have it redirected in javascript:

Add something like this to your success handler in javascript:

**Javascript** (within your success handler)

```
success: function (result) {
            if (result.success == true)
            {
               window.location = result.returnUrl;
            }
        }
```

As a side-note I would also change the rest of the `Login` method to return json rather than add errors to modelstate and return a view.

**Update**

Your `onSuccess` method would look something like this:

```
function OnSuccess(result) {
    if (result.success == true)
    {
        window.location = result.returnUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please give me example

Comment: Ok, but how to set returnUrl. Is it set from controller manually? I want returnUrl as dynamic.